# overflow property and a fixed height

Tags: html, css, overflow

look at this image folks, instead of using overflow:hidden there is still some text appearing i want to hide it too how can i do this ? 
(i don't want to reduce or increase the height, the height should be as it is)

[image]

look at the area highlighted in Red, this is what irritating me.
how can i fix this ?

this is the CSS of the content,

```
height:114px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:12px 12px 0;
padding-bottom:12px;
font-size:11px;
line-height:16px;
background-color:#e1f6fa;
```

[image]

here you go, of i fix it using css/html for the third content box , the fifth content box won't get fixed.
there are a lot other boxes having different content inside them so it is useless to change height, line-height proeprty. can it be done by php ? if yes then how ?

Comment: Would it work to increase the bottom padding, and decrease the height to cancel it out (that way, it will stay the same relative height, but there won't be any content in the bottom).

Comment: You have to increase the padding-bottom value or line-height

Comment: out of topic: You could change the police for your ASCII so every character will take the same width. It's far better for ascii art :)

Comment: there are thousand others content boxes in my website and all with different text inside them , increasing line-height will fix it for this particular content box but it will generate same problem for other content boxes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `height` property is a multiple of the `line-height` value. That will fix this. For ex: for a `line-height` of `16px`, you can have a `height` of `96px`, `112px` etc. A height of `114px` leaves `2 pixels` at the bottom which will inevitably display the leading 1~2 pixels (depending on font used) of the next line of text.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create new id or class for particular content box. For example

```
.content_box p{
Line-height:20px;
}

Html View

<div class="content_box">
<p>test message</p>
</div>
```

It is not affect the other content boxes.

Comment: this problem is not occuring in that particular box :S with your code i can fix it for specific content box but it will stays with other boxes. can it be done through php , btw this is one of the wordpress post

Comment: Every wordpress post have particular css. You have to try this code:       .wp_post_class p{
Line-height:20px;
}

Html View

<div class="wp_post_class">
<p>test message</p>
</div>

Comment: there are over 900 posts :S, look at the first post of mine i've added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing line-height or font size. I don't believe that there is any other way to do it with css.